# Conditionals: check type of element

Tags: ansible

I'm looking for a syntax to check if a variable contains any subelements or is just a string. Lets say I have a file `vars/myvars.yml`

```
myvars: {
  key1: {
    greeting: "hello"
  },
  key2: {
    greeting: {
      en: "hi",
      fr: "bonjour"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm looking for a condition to only accept a string and no object. So in this case, key1.greeting should match the condition, but key2.greeting should **not**.

```
---
- name: test
  vars_files:
    - vars/myvars.yml
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - debug: 
      msg: "greeting is '{{ item.value.greeting }}'"
    when: item.value.greeting ???is type string???
    with_dict: "{{ myvars }}"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`type_debug` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#debugging-filters):

```
when: "item.value.greeting | type_debug == 'your_wanted_type'"
```

For a string `your_wanted_type` might be `AnsibleUnicode` or `unicode`, depending on how you define the value.